# How do I get a new garage built?

Tags: garage, construction

My old 100 year old detached one-car garage is falling apart and I need a new one built from new foundation and electrical to driveway and roof....but I haven't a clue as to how to find an outfit that knows how to do this and is willing to do it without taking me to the cleaners.

Do I look for a "builder" (aren't they just interested in working on developments)?
Do I look for a contractor? (aren't they just interested in installing cabinets and windows?)
Do I look for a handyman? (won't he/she just want to paint my dining room?)

Any (useful) direction would help!

Comment: A general contractor/builder is what you would look for.

Answer (score 1):

There are contracting outfits that specialize specifically in doing garages. I used one to build me a 28x36 foot garage that had the capabilities to do all the work of preparing the site, making the foundation and floor structure and building the garage itself which they were happy to customize a bit as to where I wanted windows and service doors. When the garage was finished they were there to lay down a huge new driveway.

Answer (score 0):

I am planning on building a garage this year and found my candidates through my local lumber yard. NOT my local big box home improvement store.

Answer (score 0):

Most local, smaller builders will be happy to estimate the job for you. Check with area commerce associations, builder's associations, and any other available source of reputation information.

Don't necessarily go with the cheapest quote, and look at the quality of included materials closely. Bids can vary widely even on something as seemingly simple as a garage.